# How to display small images in an HMI ? PyQt Python

Tags: python, image, pyqt

I am making my first software with an HMI.
I'm creating a tool to easily perform contour detection on an image and make small images for each contour that's detected. So far I managed to do all of that. Now I wish to display the small images obtained into my HMI. **Currently I stopped after generating and saving the small images on my PC.** I thus have them already. I'm now trying to find some way to display them all at once in the tool part of my HMI. The problem is I don't really know where to start to do such.

I'm not asking for a complete working code but just for clues or tips that could help me figure out how I can proceed to display them. I heard about QIcon, could that maybe do it for example ?

To help you understand better my idea, here is a screenshot of my HMI. In red is how I would like to display small images from my computer as a mosaic with some scroll bar to display the next images in case they don't all fit in the space.

Thank you for all the ideas you can give me !!

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, what are you referring to with HMI?

Comment: Human-Machine interface, sorry if it was unclear ! It's the interface between the computer and the human user that uses the software.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were referring to some external library. So, the term is correct, but in programming the common convention is to call it UI.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use a [QScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html), with a basic QWidget container and a QGridLayout, and add [QLabel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html) objects with [QPixmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) images set using `setPixmap('path/to/image.png')`. Alternatively, use a [QListWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html), ensure that you set the [`viewMode()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#viewMode-prop) to `IconMode` and add QListWidgetItems, each one with a QIcon that uses the path to the image.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I'm gonna go check what you talked about and see what I can achieve with it ! :)